# Prove that norm $\| y \|=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}| y(x)|^2 dx}$ forms a linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Prove that norm
$$\mid\mid y \mid\mid=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)|}^2 dx}$$
forms a linear space.

I am troubled at $$\mid\mid y+ \hat{y}\mid\mid\leq\mid\mid y\mid\mid + \mid\mid \hat{y}\mid\mid$$
because

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)+\hat{y}(x)|}^2 dx}
&=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)|^2dx} +2y(x)\hat{y}(x)+{| \hat{y}(x)|}^2 dx}\\
&\leq\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)|}^2 dx}+\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| \hat{y}(x)|}^2 dx} \end{align*}

doesn't feel right. Is the middle term $2y(x)\hat{y}(x)$ really small enough? Yes, it can be negative, but it also can be positive. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you prove that $\langle x,y\rangle=\int_a^b x(t)y(t)\ dt$ (with obvious adjustments for complex scalars) is an inner product, the fact that $\|y\|$ is a norm follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof relies on the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, namely that
$$\int_a^b y(x)\hat{y}(x)\ dx\leq\left(\int_a^b y(x)^2\ dx\right)^\frac{1}{2} \left(\int_a^b \hat{y}(x)^2\ dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}.$$
Once you have this, the line of reasoning becomes
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)+\hat{y}(x)|}^2 dx}
&=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)|^2dx} +2\int_a^by(x)\hat{y}(x)\ dx+\int_a^b| \hat{y}(x)|^2 dx}\\
&\leq\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)|^2dx} +2\left(\int_a^b |y(x)|^2\ dx\right)^\frac{1}{2} \left(\int_a^b |\hat{y}|(x)^2\ dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}+\int_a^b| \hat{y}(x)|^2 dx } \\
&=\sqrt{\left(\left(\int_a^b|y(x)|^2\ dx \right)^\frac{1}{2} +\left(\int_a^b|\hat{y}(x)|^2\ dx \right)^\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} \\
&=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| y(x)|}^2 dx}+\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}{| \hat{y}(x)|}^2 dx}. \end{align*}

Comment: Yes. Very nice from you. I am familiar with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but it just did not even cross my mind at this case. I should have seen it!